# jQuery: menu bar similar to "tabs" but without changing divs

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out how to generate tabs like [jQuery's tabs plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), but without the swapping of DIVs. In other words, I'd like a jQuery plugin that just draws the tab bar (and lets me specify which tab is selected). I'll take care of drawing the content and having things happen when tabs are clicked.

Comment: What kind of solution are you looking for, the CSS to make tabs?

Comment: Ideally a jQuery plugin... was hoping tabs was built off another plugin that did the actual drawing, but it doesn't appear that's the case. I want to stick with jQuery if at all possible, since I like the way ThemeRoller works and I have a stylesheet ready. My goal is to not "manually" have to make the tabs.

Comment: Eric, this can be done with only CSS of course. Not sure what you mean by "drawing" or "manually make the tabs", even the jquery UI just uses CSS to create the appearance, which seems to be all you're after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do, is copy the classes that jQuery UI applies to the tabs, and you're all set.

You'll also then add/remove classes dynamically when the user clicks on one of them.

This is actually the way that jQuery UI does it with the tabs.

Here are some sample classes that they use:

```
ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all
```

I got these by inspecting the DOM after the jQuery UI has already applied the tabs functionality. Do the same, and you'll see exactly what classes you need for which elements.

**EDIT:**

Here's the complete HTML:

```
<div class="ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#">The selected tab</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#">Other tabs</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#">Other tabs</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here's the Javascript:

```
$('.ui-tabs-nav li').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
})
.mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
})
.click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active')
        .siblings().removeClass('ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active');

    return false;
});
```

And, of course, where would we be without the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Bsa7J/ .

Comment: I see what you mean-- I like the idea, though it's a little more into the guts of jQuery than I'd prefer. This may be the best answer, though, if there's no more elegant way. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: @Eric: If that was still not enough, I've now added **all** the code you need to make it work.

Comment: More elegant than I thought! Thanks for spelling it all out. I'm on board now ;-)